# Replace all chars with space except one word

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$string = 'onetwothreefourfive';
```

How can I turn this into

```
$string = '      three        ';
```

When my input is `three`?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: @egrunin, hope you are fine? #quake? `preg_replace('~[^<three>]~', ' ', $string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use crude string manipulation, **regex to the rescue**!

```
$string = preg_replace('/(three\K)?./s', ' ', $string);
```

For details on what is used, if anything is unclear, check out the [PCRE Pattern Syntax](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax) chapter of the PHP manual.

Comment: @powtac see http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape -- it's used here to stop `three` being part of the match, and so it won't get replaced.

Comment: `\K` is only valid after PHP 5.2.4

Comment: @Tugo, woe betide anyone still using such an ancient version of PHP.

Comment: @salathe - humor is always appreciated, have a wonderful day/night :)

Comment: @salathe and @ Tuga FYI: The latest SUSE Enterprise comes with PHP 5.2.6! http://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=11&service_pack=sp1&architecture=i386&package_name=index_all

Answer (score 1):

No need to use expensive and/or complicated regex:

```
function replace_space($str, $keep, $hold) {
   $str = explode($keep, $str);
   foreach ($str as &$piece) {
      $piece = str_repeat($hold, strlen($piece));
   }
   return implode($keep, $str);
}

echo replace_space('onetwothreefourfivethreefour', 'three', ' ');
```

Tested and works with multiple needles in the haystack.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first_chunk = str_repeat(' ', strpos($string, 'three'));
$last_chunk = str_repeat(' ', strlen($string) - strpos($string, 'three') - strlen($string));

$string = $first_chunk . 'three' . $last_chunk;
```

not tested, doesn't handle multiple needles in the haystack, YMMV, yada yada yada.

Comment: Looks good, forgot about `strpos`, but still locking for a neat oneliner ;)